# ProcessBatchData - update a currency field

Tags: localization, splist

I'm using SPWeb.ProcessBatchData to update list items, and I'm having a problem with currency field. When I insert something like this

```
<SetVar Name=\"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office#MyFiled\">2777,88</SetVar>
```

the value inserted into sharepoint list is 277 788,00. The comma is the correct delimiter for my locale settings (polish).
I can't figure out the format, in which the value would be inserted properly. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ok, it seems that the solution is to return number as string and replace comma with dot - apparently with ProcessBatchData regional settings of the site are not used, so I had to provide the number with standard english-version format